# Jenkins Batch-file running .NET Console Application: No output

Tags: c#, jenkins

I've got a application that builds on Jenkins (on Windows), and after the build finishes I'd like to use a custom tool written in C# to create a package from the build results, i.e. prepare them for deployment. This runs fine, however the output of the tool is not shown in the jenkins console. All I get is something like

```
D:\Jenkins\workspace\Project>D:\Tools\PackagesCreator.exe /noGui /inputFolder="D:\Jenkins\workspace\Project\bin\Release" /outputFolder="D:\Release" /overwrite
D:\Jenkins\workspace\Project>exit 0
```

As the command in the Jenkins project configuration I just wrote

```
D:\Tools\PackagesCreator.exe /noGui /inputFolder="%WORKSPACE%\bin\Release" /outputFolder="D:\Release" /overwrite
```

The `PackagesCreator` tool is using `Console.WriteLine()` (I also tried `Console.Error.WriteLine()`), which works fine when it's called directly from `cmd`.

How can I make Jenkins display the output of my custom tool?

Comment: Strange. In the tools I use, Console.WriteLine() works as expected. But there might be a catch: you use a parameter `/noGUI` which indicates to me that you actually use a Windows Forms or WPF application instead of a "real" console application.

Comment: That's true, it's WinForms. If `/noGui` is set, I use `if (!AttachConsole(-1)) { AllocConsole(); }` to enable it, and don't open the main `Form`.